# Unable to run my Django Site (Version 1.6) on Apache Server

Tags: django, apache

I am running a site that was previously running on django 1.4, but now I shifted it on django 1.6.

I am able to run my site on both version using python manage.py shell.

I am running it nicely on Apache when i keep django 1.4 virtual environment python path in Apache site-enabled, but it does not work when i keep django 1.6 virtual environment python path there.

For django 1.6 it throws error:

> ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings

What can be problem? Any changes required in wsgi.py file for django 1.6? Please help.

my virtualhost file is :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin vidya.sagar0911@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /home/vidya/workspace/vidya/vidya_rose/cms/trunk/demo/
    ServerName www.vidblog.com
    <Directory /home/vidya/workspace/vidya/vidya_rose/cms/trunk/demo>
            #Order deny,allow
            #Allow from all
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    Alias /media /home/vidya/workspace/vidya/vidya_rose/cms/trunk/demo/vidyamedia/
    Alias /static /home/vidya/workspace/vidya/vidya_rose/cms/trunk/demo/static/
    WSGIDaemonProcess www.demo.com user=www-data group=www-data processes=8 threads=75\
    python-path=/home/vidya/workspace/djnago1.6/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup www.vidblog.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/vidya/workspace/vidya/vidya_rose/cms/trunk/demo/demo/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please explain your upgrade process; and your file system layout.

Comment: is your python path really djnago1.6 not django1.6? Just wondering if its typo or not :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the issue when you are migrating your old projects from django-1.x(<1.6) to [django-1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.6/) you need to define **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE** before you call **get_wsgi_application**

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourproject.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```